# Customizing fs module it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make fs module object oriented and i made this method it returns `undefined` but when i remove it and run it it works. whats wrong?

```js
readFileAsync = () => {
        fs.readFile(this.filename, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new err;
            } else {
                return data.toString();
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: `.readFile()` is already asynchronous (which is also the "problem" you have)

Comment: @Andreas So changes i can make? remove that method?

Comment: @Haiderali - Or make it return a [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises), but note that there's already a promise-based version of `readFile` in the standard Node.js API.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You mean make a new Promise and return it?

Comment: @Haiderali - See the link. But again, [that function already exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options), I'd just use it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You mean that what I’m doing is useless right? Cuz the function already exists

Comment: @Haiderali - I'm saying that writing a promise wrapper around `fs.readFile` would be pointless; there already is one. I don't know what the broader scope of what you're doing is, so can't comment on that.